# Using a BlackBerry Bold as an IP Modem on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, modem, blackberry

I recently installed Windows 7 and now cannot use my BlackBerry Bold as a modem (via a USB cable):

- When I query the modem it is successful. I have added the correct "at" commands.
- When I try connect it says "connecting modems" but then it times out with the following error:

> Error 638: The remote server is not
>   responding in a timely fashion.

I also have the latest desktop manager software installed.

Comment: You should specify your carrier. Configuring the modem is different for, say, T-Mobile and Verizon. I would suggest editing your question to reflect this information.  There are also several different Blackberry models called "Bold", e.g. 9000 and 9700.  Please specify which one you have.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the latest version of Desktop Manager-5.0.1? This provides an IP Modem feature. With this, all you have to do is tell it what carrier you are using, and it will create a connection for you. I have tested this on several different machines with a Bold 9000 and Windows 7, and it's worked every time.